# Convert nested list with different names to data.frame filling NA and adding column

Tags: r, list, dataframe, nested-lists, rbind

I need a base R solution to convert nested list with different names to a data.frame

```
mylist <- list(list(a=1,b=2), list(a=3), list(b=5), list(a=9, z=list('k'))

convert(mylist)
## returns a data.frame:
##
##     a     b    z           
##     1     2    <NULL>   
##     3    NA    <NULL>   
##    NA     5    <NULL>   
##     9    NA    <chr [1]>
```

I know this could be easily done with `dplyr::bind_rows` or `data.table::rbindlist` with `fill = TRUE` (not ideal though since it fills character column with `NULL`, not `NA`), but I do really need a solution in base R. To simplify the problem, it is also fine with a 2-level nested list that has no 3rd level lists such as

```
mylist <- list(list(a=1,b=2), list(a=3), list(b=5), list(a=9, z='k'))

convert(mylist)
## returns a data.frame:
##
##     a     b    z           
##     1     2    NA   
##     3    NA    NA   
##    NA     5    NA   
##     9    NA    k
```

I have tried something like

```
convert <- function(L) as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, L))
```

This does not fill `NA` and add additional column `z`

### Update

`mylist` here is just a simplified example. In reality I could not assume the names of the sublist elements (`a`, `b` and `z` in the example), nor the sublists lengths (2, 1, 1, 2 in the example).

Here are the assumptions for expected `data.frame` and the input `mylist`:

1. The column number of the expected `data.frame` is determined by the maximum length of the sublists which could vary from 1 to several hundreds. There is no explicit source of information about the length of each sublist (which names will appear or disappear in which sublist is unknown)
   `max(sapply(mylist, length)) <= 1000 ## ==> TRUE`
2. The row number of the expected `data.frame`  is determined by the length of `mylist` which could vary from 1 to several thousands
   `dplyr::between(length(mylist), 0, 10000) ## ==> TRUE`
3. No explicit information for the names of the sublist elements and their orders, therefore the column names and order of the expected `data.frame` can only be determined intrinsically from `mylist`
4. Each sublist contains elements in types of `numeric`, `character` or `list`. To simplify the problem, consider only  `numeric` and `character`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A shorter solution in base R would be

```r
make_df <- function(a = NA, b = NA, z = NA) {
  data.frame(a = unlist(a), b = unlist(b), z = unlist(z))
}

do.call(rbind, lapply(mylist, function(x) do.call(make_df, x)))
#>    a  b    z
#> 1  1  2 <NA>
#> 2  3 NA <NA>
#> 3 NA  5 <NA>
#> 4  9 NA    k
```

---

**Update**

A more general solution using the same method, but which does not require specific names would be:

```r
build_data_frame <- function(obj) {
  nms     <- unique(unlist(lapply(obj, names)))
  frmls   <- as.list(setNames(rep(NA, length(nms)), nms))
  dflst   <- setNames(lapply(nms, function(x) call("unlist", as.symbol(x))), nms)
  make_df <- as.function(c(frmls, call("do.call", "data.frame", dflst)))
  
  do.call(rbind, lapply(mylist, function(x) do.call(make_df, x)))
}
```

This allows

```r
build_data_frame(mylist)
#>    a  b    z
#> 1  1  2 <NA>
#> 2  3 NA <NA>
#> 3 NA  5 <NA>
#> 4  9 NA    k
```

Comment: I like the simplicity of this solution. However, there is no way to explicitly determine the column names and order. Please see the update of the question

Comment: @englealuze ah, I see. Check my update, which contains a more general solution.

Comment: Two questions: 1. how call objects `unlist(*)` inside `dflst` get evaluated? I could understand for the outer one `call("do.call", "data.frame", dflst))` you convert it to a function and apply it to actual parameters. But I could not understand how the inner call `unlist(*)` gets evaluated. 2. The example in `as.function` man page uses `alist`. When I try `as.function(alist(a =, call('abs', as.symbol("a"))))` it does not generate true function. I have to use `as.function(c(a = NA, call('abs', as.symbol("a"))))` as you did. Why?

Comment: The call objects inside `dflist` don't get evaluated until the `do.call("data.frame", dflist)` is run. But since this is itself in the body of `make_df`, it is only invoked when `make_df` is called. At this point, the function `make_df` is effectively  `function(a = NA, b = NA, z = NA) data.frame(a = unlist(a), b = unlist(b), z = unlist(z))` . None of the arguments or calls in the function are evaluated until `make_df` is called in the final `lapply` call on the last line.

Comment: The arguments in `alist` are unevaluated, so `as.function(alist(a =, {abs(a)}))` probably does what you intend.

Comment: Thanks. It is more general to use `lapply` than `sapply` in `nms <- unique(unlist(sapply(obj, names)))`. If all sublists have same names and lengths, `sapply` without simplification returns a matrix and leads to error. So, `lapply` is more general

Answer (score 2):

We can try the base R code below

```
subset(
    Reduce(
        function(...) {
            merge(..., all = TRUE)
        },
        Map(
            function(k, x) cbind(id = k, list2DF(x)),
            seq_along(mylist), mylist
        )
    ),
    select = -id
)
```

which gives

```
   a  b  z
1  1  2 NA
2  3 NA NA
3 NA  5 NA
4  9 NA  k
```

Comment: The readability of this purely functional approach is unrivaled. The idea of reduce + merge is so smart. After seeing this solution, I ask myself why I did not do it this way. I should have been able to come up with the idea myself

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like the following:

```
mylist <- list(list(a=1,b=2), list(a=3), list(b=5), list(a=9, z='k'))

convert <- function(mylist){
  col_names <- NULL
  # get all the unique names and create the df
  for(i in 1:length(mylist)){
    col_names <- c(col_names, names(mylist[[i]]))
  }
  col_names <- unique(col_names)
  df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol=length(col_names),
                          nrow=length(mylist)))
  colnames(df) <- col_names
  
  # join data to row in df
  for(i in 1:length(mylist)){
    for(j in 1:length(mylist[[i]])){
      df[i, names(mylist[[i]])[j]] <- mylist[[i]][names(mylist[[i]])[j]]
    }
  }
  return(df)
}

df <- convert(mylist)
```

```
> df
   a  b    z
1  1  2 <NA>
2  3 NA <NA>
3 NA  5 <NA>
4  9 NA    k
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got a solution. Note this only uses the pipe, and could be exchanged for native pipe, etc.

```r
mylist %>% 
  #' first, ensure that the 2nd level is flat,
  lapply(. %>% lapply(FUN = unlist, recursive = FALSE)) %>%
  #' replace missing vars with `NA`
  lapply(function(x, vars) {
    x[vars[!vars %in% names(x)]]<-NA
    x
  }, vars = {.} %>% unlist() %>% names() %>% unique()) %>%
  do.call(what = rbind) %>%
  #' do nothing
  identity()
```

In `{.}` it is meant to define and evaluate the function formed by `unlist` followed by `names`. Otherwise `. %>% unlist() %>% names()` just defines the function, and not evaluate on the input `.`.

Comment: This solution miss 5 at the 3rd row in `b` column (assigned NA instead) and wrongly put `"k"` at the 4th row in `b` column. `"k"` should be at 4th in `z` column. Also can you please explain the usage of `.` in first `lapply` and `var = {.}`?